# How do I change the timezone to UTC?

Tags: time

I just installed a Ubuntu 11.10 box and I'm trying to figure out how to set the timezone to UTC. I have it set to London at the moment, but UTC doesn't appear to be an option.

Help?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuTime

Comment: click on time indicator at top right conrner, you will get option of Time and date settings :)

Comment: I know how to change my timezone, but there doesn't appear to be a UTC setting.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Change the timezone in a server or a desktop version? If the desktop, are you trying to add UTC to the indicator-datetime or you want to configure the network time? Your question is a little ambiguous and would require some additional info about what you have already tried and where you tried adding UTC so we can better guide you.

Comment: I think UTC appears there as GMT.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

then go to "Etc" or "None of the above", there to UTC, enter, you're done. It actually changes files `/etc/timezone` and `/etc/localtime`.

Answer (score 10):

Unable to find UTC or GMT in the menu, I ended up running tzselect from the command prompt. I selected 11, enter posix standard time, then entered UTC-0. This appears to have done it.

thanks for all of the help.

Comment: Thanks, "UTC" only was too simple, struggled a bit with this.

Answer (score 2):

This is an ugly hack, but it appears that Iceland uses year-round UTC. So setting the time zone to `Atlantic/Reykjavik` should work (at least until Iceland decides to change its default time zone).

(London doesn't use year-round UTC, so that's not going to work correctly.)

Answer (score 1):

To change the time zone for your user only on the command line; edit your `~/.bashrc` file and add this to it:

```
export TZ=UTC
```

Comment: Isn't that just my personal timezone? I'm trying to set the one for the server.